# change the paths for boost libs in Blender's CMake config

Tags: boost, build, cmake, blender

I need help on how to compile blender using the boost I have installed on my machine. I have to change the paths for boost libs in Blender's CMake config but I have no idea on how to do that. Is it one of the many cmake text files that I have to manually alterer?

this is the directions I'm following
https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Building_Blender/Mac

thanks,
      pascal

Comment: In case they are using the [`FindBoost` module](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/module/FindBoost.html), you should have success with specifying `BOOST_ROOT` (3rd green block in linked docs) with the invocation of CMake.

Comment: well thank you, but thats the thing, compiling blender has tons of cmakes and i have no idea which one is the right one to mess around with. and i tried going through all of them but got lost in how huge it is.

Comment: There are multiple `CMakeLists.txt` files, correct, however, you invoke CMake only once for the root directory. Anyway, you can set `BOOST_ROOT` as an environment variable. That should be picked up by the _FindBOOST_ module as well.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to edit any of blender's CMakeLists.txt files, the boost locations are part of the configuration of the build that you can set and alter.

As you are on a Mac and may be unfamiliar with using CLI tools, start cmake-gui and set the source and build directories, then click Configure, in the list of options you will find `Boost_INCLUDE_DIR` and `Boost_LIBRARY_DIR_RELEASE` - change these to suit the boost libs you want to use and then click Configure and Generate. Then you can open the xcode project and compile.

[image: cmake window]

If you are using the terminal to do the build you can add options when using cmake to create the build, setting `BOOST_ROOT` at this stage will allow cmake to find the boost libs during the initial configuration.

```
cmake -G Xcode -DBOOST_ROOT=~/customlibs ../blender
```

Comment: well thanks for your solution and i would definitely would of used it... but I'm trying to do this on a mac computer and when i open cmake it is different then if it was on linix. But thank you and now i know what I'm looking for in the cmake on the blender mac build

Comment: `cmake` and `cmake-gui` should both work the same on every platform. `ccmake` is a cli version of `cmake-gui` that lets you adjust settings once the initial setup has been done.